# Have to convert from one format to another

Tags: python-3.x

I need a Python script which will convert any tabular formatted PDF document into CSV or Python Dataframe object.

Comment: Can you please provide the code you already tried so far?

Comment: I converted iris dataset from csv to pdf. Now i need to convert that iris pdf bakc to dataframe through python script.